# Task couldn't find the AL.exe using SDK Tools path

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am trying to configure Jenkins on my development server (Windows 2008 Server R2) for ASP.NET project. My development server don't have VS installed. I installed Windows 10 SDK and MS Build tools 2015.

Then I tried manually building each of the project in CMD prompt with MSBuild from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin`, some of the projects (`.csproj` file) get build successfully, and some of them throw the below error
[image]

I compared the `.csproj` file with the other successfully built files, but couldn't find the cause for the error.

Please let me know what am making wrong here.

Comment: Why it was set -1

Comment: can i get some comments

Comment: The question is borderline legit; probably the combination of poor writing (not your fault, but I am afraid it was), lack of demonstrated research and an error message in the form of a picture. You can improve the question by posting a *text* error message instead. I edited your text a bit, and also upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

When you install MS Build tools 2015, you also get a shortcut for the build environment installed in your start menu. This shortcut runs the command processor but makes it execute a batch file first, such that the environment variables and the executable path are set correctly. You must use this shortcut to perform the build.

If you are in a correct environment, simply running `msbuild` should do. If you find that you need to prepend the full path to the command name, as it seems you do, then the environment is not correct.

This is done so that you can install multiple versions of build tools side by side, and they won't clobber each other settings.